# Ao utilizar o helper view do Laravel que tipo de dado tá sendo retornado?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com dúvida ao comentar o método abaixo:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return view('painel.post.listar', compact('posts'));
}
```

Seria correto comentar desta forma:

```
/**
 * Retorna uma instância de View
 * 
 * @return object
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return view('painel.post.listar', compact('posts'));
}
```

Ou o return seria **View** e na descrição ao invés de "*Retorna uma instância de View*" seria "*Retorna um objeto*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um padrão utilizado pelo [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) é assim:

```
/**
 * Return Instance of View.
 * 
 * @return Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return view('painel.post.listar', compact('posts'));
}
```

O `helper` `view` retorna a instância da classe [`Illuminate\View\View`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/View/View.html).

Comment: Consigo fazer o output do caminho da classe?

Comment: @fabio desculpas não entendi a sua pergunta como asssim output?

Comment: Vamos supor que utilizei o helper view(), consigo saber qual foi a classe ou o namespace chamado neste processo, o intuito é se possível identificar onde a mesma está.

Comment: Opa, consegui assim "dd(get_class(view('painel.post.listar', compact('posts'))));"

Comment: @Fábio um `var_dump` já resolveria.

Answer (score 2):

A descrição inicial esta perfeita ele retorna uma instancia da View sendo assim o return é uma View.

Note que a view nada mais é do que um objeto responsável por renderizar os htmls.

Note também que diretamente na [documentaçao](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses) do laravel temos alguns exemplos de utilização e de criação da view como por exemplo os do trecho abaixo:

```
$view = View::make('greetings', $data);
```

Note que a view possui outros métodos próprios também como por exemplo o share que é responsável por compartilhar trechos de dentro de uma view como abaixo:

```
 View::share('name', 'Steve');
```

Se você reparar a própria criação da view no primeiro trecho demonstrado demonstra claramente que estamos criando um tipo de objeto View. veja em $view = View::make ....